# How to get the hash of a given source file and related source files in python?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a source file, say `a.py`, which imports `b.py` and some build-in modules. `b.py` may further import `c.py` and `d.py`, etc. In `a.py`, there is a slow operation which generates an object as result. To increase the speed, I use `pickle` module to dump the generated object and load if it has been generated before.

However, if any of the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` source codes are modified, the object should be generated again. To avoid deleting the pickle file manually every time, I want to compute the hash of the sources and write it to the pickle file. So I can check the hash code and decide whether to generate the object.

How to write a function that if given `a.py`, it will recursively find `b.py`, `c.py`, and `d.py`, and compute the hash code alltogether?

Are there any better ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: I think this is a little complicated, you are trying to make a compiler's function.

Comment: It's confusing. Are you generating object or module? In one sentence you say module and in other you say object. *Yes. I know that a module has a representation in Python being an object of type `module` but I want to understand the concept*

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Sorry for my mistake. I mean generate an object, and it cost a lot of time.

Comment: I think the problem in finding all "relevant" files is that you have to know, which imports to follow and which are not.  I would have all relevant files in one directory, list all those files anding on `.py`, make one string of the content of all thise files and hash it.

Comment: @jochen I think I can just follow the source files that in the same folder as a.py. But I don't know how to get the list of imported source files.

Comment: @jochen that's wrong. You can't anticipate how the update of i.e. third party library will influence the generated object.

Comment: I think I can just follow the source files that in the same folder, i.e., the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import sys
for name, module in sys.modules.iteritems():
    # module object is a representation of imported module
    try:
        # Next line shows how to access path of Python module file
        module.__file__ 
    except AttributeError:
        '''
        Built-in modules and other special cases don't have __file__
        attribute but you shouldn't care about them as their behaviour won't change
        '''
```

Now you can calculate and compare your hashes. But honestly I would say that comparing file modification time is enough and cheaper than calculating hashes.

Output of `print sys.modules` in my case is:

```
{'copy_reg': <module 'copy_reg' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc'>, 'sre_compile': <module 'sre_compile' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc'>, '_sre': <module '_sre' (built-in)>, 'encodings': <module 'encodings' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc'>, 'site': <module 'site' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.pyc'>, '__builtin__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'sysconfig': <module 'sysconfig' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc'>, 'atexit': <module 'atexit' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/atexit.pyc'>, '__main__': <module '__main__' (built-in)>, 'encodings.encodings': None, 'abc': <module 'abc' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/abc.pyc'>, 'posixpath': <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>, '_weakrefset': <module '_weakrefset' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc'>, 'errno': <module 'errno' (built-in)>, 'encodings.codecs': None, 'sre_constants': <module 'sre_constants' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc'>, 're': <module 're' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.pyc'>, '_abcoll': <module '_abcoll' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc'>, 'types': <module 'types' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/types.pyc'>, '_codecs': <module '_codecs' (built-in)>, 'encodings.__builtin__': None, '_warnings': <module '_warnings' (built-in)>, 'genericpath': <module 'genericpath' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/genericpath.pyc'>, 'stat': <module 'stat' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/stat.pyc'>, 'zipimport': <module 'zipimport' (built-in)>, '_sysconfigdata': <module '_sysconfigdata' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc'>, 'warnings': <module 'warnings' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/warnings.pyc'>, 'UserDict': <module 'UserDict' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.pyc'>, 'encodings.utf_8': <module 'encodings.utf_8' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc'>, 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, 'codecs': <module 'codecs' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/codecs.pyc'>, 'readline': <module 'readline' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so'>, 'os.path': <module 'posixpath' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>, '_locale': <module '_locale' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so'>, 'rlcompleter': <module 'rlcompleter' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/rlcompleter.pyc'>, 'signal': <module 'signal' (built-in)>, 'traceback': <module 'traceback' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/traceback.pyc'>, 'linecache': <module 'linecache' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.pyc'>, 'posix': <module 'posix' (built-in)>, 'encodings.aliases': <module 'encodings.aliases' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc'>, 'exceptions': <module 'exceptions' (built-in)>, 'sre_parse': <module 'sre_parse' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc'>, 'os': <module 'os' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'>, '_weakref': <module '_weakref' (built-in)>}
```

**EDIT:**

How about:

```
import sys
import copy

# Save the dict of imported modules
modules_before = copy.copy(sys.modules)

# Import b, which will import c and d and so on
import b

for name, module in sys.modules.iteritems():
    if name in modules_before:
        # Skip irrelevant modules
        continue
    # module object is a representation of imported module
    try:
        # Next line shows how to access path of Python module file
        module.__file__ 
    except AttributeError:
        '''
        Built-in modules and other special cases don't have __file__
        attribute but you shouldn't care about them as their behaviour won't change
        '''
```

Comment: I agree with you. Comparing the modification time is a better idea.

Comment: It seems this will list not only the modules imported by a.py, but ALL the modules imported by the Python runtime.

Comment: Yes. And the problem is?

Comment: If you really insist on checking only modules in a specific folder and subfolders - `if module.__file__.startswith('/path/to/my/fancy/folder'):` but checking modification time of everything what was imported is still a matter of miliseconds.

Comment: Assume there is a top.py, it imports something_else.py and a.py. If top.py, something_else.py or any files that imported by something_else.py are modifed, the object will be regenerated.

Comment: So the object will be regenerated when it does not have to.